# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' On VS-CODE while opening Jupyter Notebook file

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to run a jupyter notebook for webscraping on vscode using BeautifulSoup, the file imports 'requests' library, nd beautifulsoup from bs4, but it is not working, I am getting an error saying no module found for requests.[image]

I've tried updating pip through the terminal and i've changed directory and tried installing it using --user, i've also tried updating the python but to no avail.

Comment: The python environment jupyter is using is probably not the global one... What is the interpreter path inside jupyter?

Comment: `requests` is not standard module. Did you install `requests` ? `pip install requests` ?

Comment: I idi install requests.